# How to pass argument from a text file in mid of linux command

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting

This is my command

`aws elb describe-tags --profile dev --load-balancer-name ELBNAME |grep   -Pwo "Product\K\b.*|Environment\K.*|TAGDESCRIPTIONS\K.*" | xargs`

And instead of **ELBNAME** i want to pass **text file** that is having multiple ELBNAME line by line.

I want this command should take all the ELBNAME One by one & output also should be line by line.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried this "$(< elbname1.txt)"
$(cat elbname.txt)
`cat elbname.txt`

Comment: `"$(< elbname1.txt)"` after trying this getting this error.

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeTags operation: LoadBalancer name cannot be longer than 32 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a small script for you which will work. In the list of ELB in your text file are separated by space or new line, I hope.

```
#!/bin/bash
elb_name=($(cat test.txt))
for (( k = 0; k < ${#elb_name[@]}; k++ ))
do
echo -e "Describing tags for ELB - ${elb_name[k]} \n";
aws elb describe-tags --profile dev --load-balancer-name ${elb_name[k]} | grep  -Pwo "Product\K\b.*|Environment\K.*|TAGDESCRIPTIONS\K.*" | xargs
echo -e "End of describing tags for ELB - ${elb_name[k]} \n";
done
```